# What are the topological properties of the metric space retained (inherited) for its completion

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, reference-request, big-list

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(\bar{X},\bar{d})$ its completion.
There is a list of topological properties 
[Wikipedia - Topological property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property)

Does anybody know list which of them are retained (inherited) for completion?
For example

1. if $(X,d)$ is locally compact space then $\bar{X}$ may be non-locally compact space.(Consider the induced path metric space on the following subset of the Euclidean plane: $(0,1] \times \{ 0 \}\cup (0,1]\times \{1\}\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{1/n\}\times [0,1] $.)
2. if $(X,d)$ is separable space then $\bar{X}$ is separable space.
3. if $(X,d)$ is connected space then $\bar{X}$ is connected space.
4. if $(X,d)$ is path-connected space then $\bar{X}$ may be non path-connected space. (consider the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ in the plane for positive $x$. )

I am interested in this problem in general, especially for the spaces with intrinsic metric.

Comment: You mean, which properties are retained when passing from a space to its completion?

Comment: Could you please give some examples of properties you're interested in and for which you don't know the answer?

Comment: Example 4 is not true: consider the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ in the plane for positive $x$.

Comment: Some of these are trivial (or at least very elementary). For instance, 2 is true because any countable dense subset of $X$ is a countable dense subset of $\overline{X}$, since $X$ is dense in its completion. Similarly, anything between a connected set and its closure in a topological space is connected. In particular, if $X$ is connected then so is its completion. You probably should have thought a little bit harder about some of these. 

Comment: @Joel, Pete Point taken. My mistake. 

Comment: @ Joel David Hamkins Thanks.
@ Keenan Kidwell May be you should read the question more carefully.

Comment: @ Stefan Geschke Yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "the spaces with intrinsic metric"?

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez Let $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $d$ is intrinsic metric if for any two points $x,y\in X$ the distance 
$d(x,y)=\inf_\gamma\{L(\gamma)\}$, where $\gamma$ is path connecting $x,y$. (See book Dmitri Burago; Yuri Burago; and Sergei Ivanov - A Course in Metric Geometry. and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric)

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer Most part of this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property ,  especially Separation, Connectedness and Compactness sections.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest that all the connectivity properties were either preserved or sometimes acquired by completion: e.g. a totally disconnected $X$ may become a path-connected $\bar X$, and the same is true for the other locally-defined connectivity properties I considered on that list.

But this is not true in the case of simple connectivity, or n-connectivity, because these properties depend on each point.  As far as I can tell you can change them any way you like.  You could put a metric on a CW-complex, but for $\bar X$ any CW complex of countably many cells, you can remove a point to change the homotopy type of $X$ as compared to $\bar X$, or just as above, let $X$ be a discrete dense set.

Or make $X$ two horizontal line segments one over the other, connected by line segments depicting an ordered bijection between dense subsets, or higher-dimensional analogues, so that $\bar X$ is a cube.

Or let $X$ be the cone of any topological space with an appropriate metric, but with the point at the tip removed, so whatever the homotopy type of $X$, $\bar X$ is contractible. I think you could even selectively remove points from a CW complex to redesign homotopy groups in more interesting ways.